# angle between vectors based on angles of related vectors

Tags: geometry

I have 2 sets of 2 real vectors with norm 1: $v_1,  v_2$ and $\hat{v}_1, \hat{v}_2$ (so $v_1 \perp v_2$ and $\hat{v}_1 \perp \hat{v}_2$). All vectors are $n$-dimensional.
We assume we know the angle $\theta_{21}$between $v_2$ and $\hat{v}_1$, the angle $\theta_{11}$ between $v_1$ and $\hat{v}_1$ and the angle $\theta_{22}$  between $v_2$ and $\hat{v}_2$. Remark that all $\theta$'s can lay in $[0, 2\pi]$ and that we do not change sign of a vector to make a $\theta$ laying in $[0, \pi]$. This means that we define the angle between $v_i, \hat{v}_j$ as $\theta_{ij} = \cos^{-1} ( v_i^T v_j)$

Is the angle $\theta_{12}$ between $v_1$ and $\hat{v}_2$ uniquely determined or not? And if so, is it possible to write it in function of $\theta_{21}, \theta_{11}, \theta_{22}$?

kind regards,

Comment: No, the angle is not uniquely determined. Let $v_1=(1,0),v_2=(0,1),\hat{v_1}=(1,1)$. Then the angle between $v_1,\hat{v_2}$ could be $\pi/4$ or $3\pi/4$. You can construct more examples in higher dimensions.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we also assume we know the angle $\theta_{11}$ between $v_1$ and $\hat{v}_1$ and the angle $\theta_{22}$ between $v_2$ and  $\hat{v}_2$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is still no. Let $v_{1}=(1,0)$, $v_{2}=(0,1)$ and $\hat{v_{1}}=(0,1)$, then $\hat{v_{2}}=(1,0)$ and $\hat{v_{2}}=(-1,0)$ have angle $0$ and $\pi$ respectively.

Comment: you miss something: the vectors $\hat{v}_1$ and $\hat{v}_2$ need to be orthonormal which is not the case in your example

Comment: Sorry, typo, should be fixed now.

Comment: Ok, I agree with your statement. I have one extra remark here: in my examples $\hat{v}_1$  and $v_1$ are close to each other and so are $\hat{v}_2$ and $v_2$. In your example $v_1 \perp \hat{v}_1$ and $v_2 \perp \hat{v}_2$. A test in my matlab script tells me that your example heavily rely on that in the sense that if you do a small perturbation on $\hat{v}_1$ and $\hat{v}_2$ and you apply the same strategy (so one time with $\hat{v}_2$  and one time with $-\hat{v}_2$ ), then it does not work anymore since the angle between $v_2$ and $\hat{v}_2$ will not stay the same in both cases